# extent report with one master test class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

i have created 2 different test classes (test1.java and test2.java), having multiple tests in each class. to simplify, i have created one master test class, in which i have created 2 tests and called the methods from test1page.java and test2page.java. now  when i create the extent reports it only gives 2 results. i want all the test result which i have created in test1.java and test2.java.

below is my MasterTest.java

```
public class MasterTest extends TestBase {

@BeforeClass()
//before class method

@Test(priority=1)
// methods from the test1page.java class

@Test(priority=2)
// methods from the  test2page.java class

@AfterClass
    }
```

below is my xml file to run

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="smoke">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="report.TestListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="master">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.MasterTest">

            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Why have you used MasterTest? Is it to avoid two entries of classes in testng xm?

Comment: yes, if i use 2 entries in xml file, its running all test in different browser. i want all my tests should run on a single browser instance.

Comment: Have you tried `<packages></packages>` instead of <classes>

Comment: no i have not, will it run all the test from the package? because i need to run only some classes from the same package.